# SQL case when X LIKE '%T%' in Python script resulting in "TypeError: dict is not a sequence"

Tags: python, sql

I am attempting to run a SQL query against a Redshift DB in a Python script. The following results in an error "TypeError: dict is not a sequence" and I cannot figure out why.

```
test1 = """

WITH A AS
(
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN substring(text_value, 0, 4) LIKE ' ' THEN substring(substring(text_value, 0, 4), 3) ELSE substring(text_value, 0, 4) END AS cost_center_id
FROM job_custom_fields
WHERE key = 'cost_center'
)

SELECT job_id,
display_value,
           CASE WHEN cost_center_id LIKE '%T%' THEN SUBSTRING(cost_center_id, 1,1)
                WHEN cost_center_id LIKE '%D%' THEN SUBSTRING(cost_center_id, 1,1)
                WHEN cost_center_id LIKE '%P%' THEN SUBSTRING(cost_center_id, 1,1) ELSE cost_center_id END AS cost_center_id
FROM A
"""

red_engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://org_525:LZynsTS56PqPlHVhIIgUdDf1c1wuW4gD@redshift.greenhouse.io:5439/greenhouse')
test = pd.read_sql_query(test1,red_engine)
test
```

Any assistance is much appreciated

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you need to escape `%` character using `%%` in Python.

`%` is used for string formatting in Python.

Not a solution to this problem but it's worth mentioning here that in Python 3.6 and later, there is a more recommended way of string formatting using `f-strings`. For example:

```
name = 'eshirvana'
message = f"I am {name}"
print(message)
```